# Replace string with Node standard (no query) Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I have Node server that uses MariaDB (MySQL) via Sequelize.
I have some rows in my db that looks like this, for example:

| Id | clips |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["videoId123456","videoId8910111213"] |
| 2 | ["videoId123456"] |
| 3 | [] |
| 4 | ["videoId123456"] |

The "clips" column is a string, but in an array structure.

My task is to find a way to remove specific videoId from the clips column. For example, if the API route gets the Id "videoId123456", it will be deleted from rows 1,2,4. If it gets the Id "videoId8910111213" it will be deleted from row 1.

I know how to do it by pure MySQL, something like:

```
UPDATE player
SET clips = REPLACE(clips ,'"videoId1234567"','')
WHERE clips LIKE '%"videoId1234567"%';
```

I know I can run pure SQL commands with Sequelize as string like:

```
await sequelize.query(
`   UPDATE player
    SET clips = REPLACE(clips ,'"videoId1234567"','')
    WHERE clips LIKE '%"videoId1234567"%';
`, {
  type: QueryTypes.UPDATE
});
```

But I wonder if there any way to do it by pure Sequelize, something like:

```
player.update({
  'clips': 'clips.replace('"videoId1234567"','')'
   where: { 'clips': [Op.like]: '"videoId1234567"' }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `clips` look like perfectly valid JSON, which is an observation that guides how you actually work with data in that column. What is the actual table schema? Is the column _really_ a string, or is it a JSON datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Sequelize.fn` amd `Sequelize.col` to achieve the goal to use the `replace` SQL function:

```js
player.update({
  clip: Sequelize.fn('replace', Sequelize.col('clip'), '"videoId1234567"','')
}, {
   where: { clip: { [Op.like]: '"videoId1234567"' } }
});
```

P.S. It would be better not to just replace substrings in this JSON-like array and prefer using SQL functions that can work with JSON to work with an array (if it's applicable to MariaDB).